# SharePoint workflow not working for some users

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a custom approval workflow (made with SP Designer on 2010 platform) for a list made on an on-premise SP site (probably SP 2016), which works for some users, but for others - doesn't. I can't figure out why.

Here is the workflow logic:

```
If [Region] equals Europe
 If [Approval Number] is less than 1
  If [Country] equals France
    If [Workflow Context:Initiator] equals Smith, John
      Set [Comment] to "Approved by [Workflow Context:Initiator]"
      Set [Approval Number] to 1
```

This workflow is attached to an approval button (a custom action) on the top ribbon of the edit form.
The users starting it belong to the same SP group, with the same permission level.
And yet, for some users it completes without errors and updates the comment + approval number fields, and for others it also completes without errors(!), but does not update the two fields.

Additional information: although the users belong to the same SP group, they are from different teams within the organization (e.g. analysts and approvers).
It's users from only one organization team (approvers) that face this issue.

I am not sure how to look for the root cause of the issue, not to mention fix it.
I am the site owner, but I'm not an admin. Can you help me figure this out?

I tried rewriting part of the workflow, re-attaching the workflow to the custom action button, live testing with the users to confirm they were running the workflow properly, even copying the problematic record and inserting myself as an approver in the workflow (and I could successfully run it), but the affected users still cannot run the workflow properly (the crucial part is adding the comment and updating the approval number to 1).